# Interpreting arguments in watts.strogatz.game() in igraph using R

Tags: r, igraph

I am having trouble interpreting the arguments in the watts strogatz model in igraph and the documentation doesn't really help.

If I generate a network:

```
watts.strogatz.game(dim=1,size=2000,nei=10, p=0.01)
```

Here the size argument should indicate the number of nodes and the p argument the probability of rewiring.

I do not undertand the dim and nei arguments. Does dim mean the size of the network when it starts adding edges? Can someone help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edges are not added, but rewired.
The initial graph is a lattice, i.e., a very regular graph.
The `dim` and `nei` parameters describe this initial lattice (before any rewiring happens).
There are `size^dim` vertices.

Here are lattices of dimensions 1 and 2.

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph.lattice(5)
plot(g, layout=layout.grid(g,width=5))
```

[image: 1-dimensional lattice]

```
plot(graph.lattice(c(5,5)))
```

[image: 2-dimensional lattice]

In those examples, each vertex is connected to 1 neighbour in each direction:
you can change `nei` to increase this number.

```
g <- graph.lattice(10, nei=2)
plot(g, layout=layout.circle)
```

[image: More neighbours]

The lattices used are actually circular (I set `p=0` to remove the rewiring -- you can change it to see how the model works):

```
g <- watts.strogatz.game(dim=1,size=10,nei=2, p=0)
plot(g)
```

[image]